# Socket.io namespacing issues while working on a client

Tags: php, websocket, socket.io

I'm working on a CakePHP plugin to easily use a WebSocket (as a client connection to a node server). I'm stuck on making namespaces work correctly. Can someone help me ? I've checked the spec and it is quite vague on it.

Everything else works fine. I just don't fine how (and when) i should define the namespace.

While it seemed I should use `/$namespace/1/$id` for the transport, it does not work :

- I get an empty http response with a "destroying non socket.io upgrade" server side.

On the javascript client (& working) side, chrome still does the handshake on `/socket.io/1`, same for the transport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to use the connect frame `1:$namespace::` to select a new endpoint.